# How to call an interactive function and pass arguments to it from within Elisp?

Tags: interactive

I'm trying to compose a link to the `describe-package` help buffer to the `xref` package like this:

```
[[(elisp:(describe-package "xref"))][xref]]
```

But it can't execute. So I wonder how to pass arguments to an interactive function from within Elisp. I don't believe anyone has asked this question, and after much searching I still couldn't find the answer. I've tried the following forms and none of them worked.

```
(describe-package "xref")
(call-interactively 'describe-package "xref")
(call-interactively (describe-package "xref"))
(call-interactively (lambda () (interactive) (describe-package '("xref"))))
(command-execute (describe-package "xref"))
(command-execute 'describe-package "xref")
```

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Answer (score 1):

According to the docs, `describe-package` takes a symbol as argument not a string so you need:

```
(describe-package 'xref)
```